# NoReverseMatch at / Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to create sample project in it. Please help me in resolving this error.

My Main URLs.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^t20_predict/', include('PredictMatch.urls')),
]
```

My Apps URLs.py file

```
app_name = 'PredictMatch'

urlpatterns = [
# t20_predict/T20
url(r'^T20/$', views.t20index, name='t20index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

becuase

```
url(r'^T20/$', views.t20index, name='t20index')
```

you are not expecting any id ,the url is just t20_predict/T20/ -> see here there is no id

if you want the url to receive id as well the url pattern should be

```
url(r'^T20/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.t20index, name='t20index')
```

Comment: Hi Sugumar, thanks for your suggestion, it got resolved. :)